# Match multiple concept

Tags: bixby

Wish to show my input view, with a message vary from time, and showing content based on another variable.

This is my input-view

```
input-view{
    match{
        userWantToHear(this){
            from-output:getStart //action to get list of selection
        }
    }

    message{
        switch (this){//should be another value which is (timePeriod)
            case ("M"){
                template-macro (morning-template)
            }
            case ("A"){
                template-macro (afternoon-template)
            }
            case ("N"){
                template-macro (night-template)
            }
            default{
                template-macro (normal-template)
            }
        }
    }

    render{
        selection-of (this){ //this should be (userWantToHear)
            where-each (one){
                spoken-summary{ 
                    template ("#{value(one)}")
                }
                cell-card{
                    slot2{
                        content{
                            primary{
                                template ("#{value(one)}")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So what my thought is, create a structure to contain both of them.

```
structure (menu) {
  description (__DESCRIPTION__)
  property (timeperiod){
    type (timePeriod)
    min (Required) max (One)
  }

  property (whatuserwant) {
    type (userWantToHear)
    min (Required) max (One)
  }

}
```

And i also create a action to get them.

```
action (getMenu) {
  type(Search)
    collect{
        input (timeperiod){
            type (timePeriod)
            min (Required) max (One)
            default-init{
                intent{
                    goal: getTime
                }
            }
        }
    input (whatuserwant){
      type (userWantToHear)
      min (Required) max (One)
      default-init{
        intent{
          goal: getStart
        }
      }
    }
    }
  output (menu)
}
```

The result from the input-view will be pass into the action below, which is userWantToHear

```
action (getNews) {
    type (Search)
    description (__DESCRIPTION__)
    collect {
        input (whatuserwant){
            type (userWantToHear)
            min (Required) max (One)
            default-init{
                intent{
                    goal: getMenu
                }
            }
        }
    }
    output (newsAudio)
}
```

So i wonder how the input view is gonna accept the structure and access the property inside it for each section, and get back the input i want? Currently from my side, it's able to get the selection, but the message doesn't change according to "timePeriod" where i believe it doesn't pass in into the input view yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two questions here in your post.

1. How do I render different views? Answer: use if-else or switch statement to select template macros.
2. How to I access concept not in `match Type(this)`? Answer: use complicated match pattern that link these concept through an action. Consider the following code block.

```
  match: IntAge(this) {
    to-input: GetStructPerson (action)
  }
  message {
    template ("Enter age of #{value(action.name)}")
  }
```

You can read more and download sample capsule in [Bixby Developer Center](https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/articles/360045584134)

Comment: Would never thought of this, will refer to the docs more after this, Thanks a lot